# How to draw lines between specified dots on ListPlot?

Tags: plotting

I would like to create a plot where I have unconnected dots and some connected.

So far, I have figured out how to draw the dots.

My code is the following:

```
ListPlot[{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}, {1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}, {4, 7}, {1, 7}, {2, 8}, {3, 9}, {4, 10}, {1, 10}, {2, 11}, {3, 12}, {4,13}, {2.5, 7}}, Ticks -> {{1, 2, 3, 4}, None}, AxesStyle -> Thin, TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 12], Mesh -> Full]
```

I have thought using ListLinePlot command, but I don't know how to specify to the command to draw only selected lines between the dots.

Do have any suggestions/hints on how to do that?

[image: An example of what I want to do.]

Thank you.

Comment: Add this option at the end of `ListPlot`: `Epilog -> {Line[ <list of points to join> ]}`.

Comment: ...or you could use `Prolog`, if you want the line to go *under* the points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility would be to use `Epilog` with `Line`:

```
ListPlot[
  {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}, {1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}, {4, 7}, {1, 7}, {2, 8}, {3, 9}, {4, 10}, {1, 10}, {2, 11}, {3, 12}, {4, 13}, {2.5, 7}}, 
  Ticks -> {{1, 2, 3, 4}, None},
  AxesStyle -> Thin,
  TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 12],
  Mesh -> Full,
  Epilog -> {
    Line[
      {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 5}, {3, 12}}
    ]
  }
]
```

[image: ListPlot with Epilog connecting some of the points with a line.]

A bit more concise:

```
pts = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}, {1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}, {4, 7}, {1, 7}, {2, 8}, {3, 9}, {4, 10}, {1, 10}, {2, 11}, {3, 12}, {4, 13}, {2.5, 7}};

ListPlot[
  pts, 
  Ticks -> {{1, 2, 3, 4}, None},
  AxesStyle -> Thin,
  TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 12],
  Mesh -> Full,
  Epilog -> {
    Line[
      pts[[{1, 2, 6, 15}]]
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 7):

```
ListPlot[{pts, pts[[{1, 2, 6, 15}]]}, Joined -> {False, True}, 
 Ticks -> {{1, 2, 3, 4}, None}, AxesStyle -> Thin, 
 TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 12], Mesh -> Full]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

```
 p1 =
    ListPlot[{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}, {1, 4}, {2, 5}, 
          {3, 6}, {4, 7}, {1, 7}, {2, 8}, {3, 9}, {4, 10}, {1, 10}, {2, 11}, 
          {3, 12}, {4, 13}, {2.5, 7}},
          Ticks -> {{1, 2, 3, 4}, None},
          AxesStyle -> Thin,
          TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 12],
          Mesh -> Full];

p2 =
 ListLinePlot[{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 6}, {4, 10}}]

Show[p1, p2]
```

[image]