# Connect points in List plot by individual specification

Tags: plotting

I like to do the following. I have a set of points that I plot in a ListPlot. I want overlay another plot where I connect the points with a line in a specific order ( Let's say connect point 1 with 5, 5 with 2 ...)

In the following there is a toy example of how my data look like:

```
identifier = Table[i, {i, 1, 10}];
cordx = RandomReal[10, 10];
cordy = RandomReal[10, 10];
data = Transpose@{identifier, cordx, cordy};

ListPlot[data[[All, 2 ;; 3]]]
```

Comment: cannot you just `Show` it together the set of lines you want to plot?

Comment: you can specify the points to connect as a sequence, eg. `ListLinePlot[data[[{1, 5, 2}, 2 ;; 3]]]` to connect point 1 with 5, 5 with 2.

Comment: Closely related Q/A: [How to draw lines between specified dots on ListPlot?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/98558/125)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define the list of points you want to connect, here from 1->5, 3->5, 7->3, and 8->7 for example,

```
pointslist = {{1, 5}, {5, 2}, {7, 3}, {8, 7}};

Show[
 ListPlot[data[[All, 2 ;; 3]]],
 Graphics@(Line[{data[[#1, 2 ;; 3]], data[[#2, 2 ;; 3]]}] & @@@ 
    pointslist)]
```

[image]

Or, just a hair shorter,

```
ListPlot[data[[All, 2 ;; 3]], 
 Epilog -> (Line[{data[[#1, 2 ;; 3]], data[[#2, 2 ;; 3]]}] &) @@@ 
   pointslist]
```

gives the same output.

Comment: `Epilog -> (Line[{data[[#1, 2 ;; 3]], data[[#2, 2 ;; 3]]}] &) @@@ pointslist` also does the trick! (inside `ListPlot`)

Comment: @Aisamu, nice, that beats me by [6 bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4944/byte-counter-snippet)

Comment: Or, as I'd write to management, "nearly 10% increase in space-efficiency"!

Answer (score 2):

If all points are to be connected in a specified order, the following also works.

```
lst = {1, 5, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4, 9, 6, 10};
Show[ListPlot[data[[All, 2 ;; 3]]], 
    ListLinePlot[Table[data[[i]], {i, lst}][[All, 2 ;; 3]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: This is definitely the way to go if the points are all connected in a path.  I think you could shorten it by replacing the `Show[.....]` with `ListLinePlot[data[[lst, 2 ;; 3]], PlotMarkers -> Automatic]`